# Using GDAL's Python Bindings, how can I download an entire Layer?

Tags: python, gdal, wfs, ogr, gdal-python-binding

I'm trying to write a Script, which will download an entire WFS layer to Disk. The output format could be GeoJSON, Spatilite or even Shapefile.

I know how to do this using `ogr2ogr`, but I need to use the Python Bindings, since this is part of a larger Python script.

How do I download the entire layer using the GDAL bindings?

I've managed to write the following code:

```
import sys
from osgeo import ogr
driver=ogr.GetDriverByName('WFS')
url=sys.argv[3]
layerName=sys.argv[4]
wfs=driver.Open('WFS:'+url)
layer=wfs.GetLayerByName(layerName)

#I'm stuck here
#I need to save this entire Layer to disk, in any format that GDAL understands
```

Comment: What did try so far? https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html describes CopyLayer for example to save geodata from one format to another (see: Load data to memory).

Comment: Be aware that WFS usually has a limit to the number of features you can get in a single call. You might need to "paginate" through results.

Comment: @bugmenot123: In my tests, using the accepted answer, files were saved with over 5000+ records. Even the  Docs for [CopyLayer](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.DataSource-class.html#CopyLayer) says that all features will be duplicated.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the server. Iirc ArcGIS Server is really low, in the FOSS world it is in the tens of thousands. Still easy to reach if you find a nice WFS with interesting data. ;) CopyLayer will copy all you got, but the WFS might have just served you a subset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save the Data to GeoJSON by using [CreateDataSource](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Driver-class.html#CopyDataSource) and [CopyLayer](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.DataSource-class.html#CopyLayer) function. Here is some sample code:

```
dr = ogr.GetDriverByName( 'GeoJSON' )
ds = dr.CreateDataSource( 'test.json' )
ds.CopyLayer(layer, 'local_copy')
```