# Copying a WFS layer to the disk, using GDAL's Python bindings? (it creates empty files)

Tags: python, gdal, wfs, ogr

I'm quite new to ogr/gdal (both in osgeo4w shell and python) and I have tried to set up a script that should connect to a WFS and download a specific file. The best match to my problem was this stackexchange question: [Using GDAL's Python Bindings, how can I download an entire Layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208288/using-gdals-python-bindings-how-can-i-download-an-entire-layer)
Using this code, I'm able to connect to the WFS and create a local file (I think). But when I try to copy the WFS dataset to the local file, the file ends up being empty.

My own code:

```
import sys, os
from osgeo import ogr, gdal

#setting the output destination
wfs_destination = r"C:\wfs_downloads"

#the layer name im looking for
lyrname = "Bypasstilladelser"

#opening the wfs 
indriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('WFS')
url = 'http://kystatlas.kyst.dk/arcgis/services/ekstern/KDI_Bypass/MapServer/WFSServer?'
wfs_ds = indriver.Open('WFS:' + url)

#setting up a datasource for the output
outdriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
outfile = os.path.join(wfs_destination, lyrname+'.shp')
out_ds = outdriver.CreateDataSource(outfile)#)

#opening the output file in write-access mode (have tried with and without it)
tmp = outdriver.Open(outfile, 1)

#copying the layer from the wfs to the created output destination. 
out_ds.CopyLayer(wfs_ds.GetLayerByName(lyrname), outfile, ['OVERWRITE=YES'])
```

Answer (score 1):

This allows the download of a WFS as a shapefile; you just have to know the type of geometry. Tested in python3.

Excuse my English.

```
import sys, os
from osgeo import ogr, gdal

gdal.SetConfigOption('GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL', 'YES')

# Params
_OUT_DIR = r'output_directory'
_WFS_URL = 'the_url_of_your_wfs'
_GEOMETRY = 'the_geometry'     # options: point, line, polygon

_DRIVER_NAME_WFS = 'WFS'
_DRIVER_NAME_SHAPEFILE = 'ESRI Shapefile'
    
driver_wfs = ogr.GetDriverByName(_DRIVER_NAME_WFS)
wfs = driver_wfs.Open(f'{_DRIVER_NAME_WFS}:{_WFS_URL}')

layer_count = wfs.GetLayerCount()

for i in range(layer_count):
    layer = wfs.GetLayerByIndex(i)
    layer_name = layer.GetName()
    driver_shapefile = ogr.GetDriverByName(_DRIVER_NAME_SHAPEFILE)
    out_feature = os.path.join(_OUT_DIR, f'{layer_name}.shp')
    data_source = driver_shapefile.CreateDataSource(out_feature)
    prj = layer.GetSpatialRef()
    if _GEOMETRY_TYPE == 'point':
        geom = ogr.wkbPoint
    elif _GEOMETRY_TYPE == 'line':
        geom = ogr.wkbLineString
    elif _GEOMETRY_TYPE == 'polygon':
        geom = ogr.wkbPolygon
    layer_new = data_source.CreateLayer(layer_name, prj, geom)
    layer_def = layer.GetLayerDefn()
    for field in range(layer_def.GetFieldCount()):
        field_name = layer_def.GetFieldDefn(field).GetName()
        if field_name in ('SHAPE.STArea__', 'SHAPE.STLength__'):
            continue
        layer_new.CreateField(layer_def.GetFieldDefn(field))
    
    for row in layer:
        layer_new.CreateFeature(row)
```

Comment: your `_GEOMETRY` variable should be `_GEOMETRY_TYPE` I assume...

Comment: Can i use this to download arcgis wfs layers?